# GeoCoding returns ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: google-api, reverse-geocoding

The following is my query:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.477752,-2.266695&result_type=street_address&key=*****
```

and it returns empty result:

```
{
   "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "FPHM+48 Salford, UK",
      "global_code": "9C5VFPHM+48"
   },
   "results": [],
   "status": "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

I have tested the coordinates 53.477752,-2.266695 on https://www.latlong.net with the place name "Manchester" and the website is showing King Street which is correct. Why GoogleAPI returns ZERO_RESULTS? Is this issue a still bug in Google or do I need to add additional parameters?

Comment: Thanks @MrUpsidown, I recon it is a bug in GeoCoding. I googled the ZERO_RESULTS issue today and found so many complaints from developers. My API request format is correct; I double checked. Also the API returns proper street address info for majority of my requests but some of them cannot be resolved. The one given above is one of them.

Comment: My bad, sorry. This is reverse geocoding and I looked at the doc for normal geocoding... What you *should* do anyway is to properly [URL-encode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs) your request, in case you haven't done so.

Comment: Why do I need to do URL encoding? There is no spaces or escape chars on the request url. Just decimals and keywords with underscore _ are on the url.

Answer (score 0):

Upon testing the coordinate (53.477752,-2.266695), I was able to get a couple of results. However, it seems that not one of the address results contains the `result_type` "**street_address**". This is the reason why you get zero results as a response, since you've added a `result_type=street_address` filter in the query.

Please see the [Geocoder tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D53.477752%252C-2.266695) to see the actual results. Here's the sample request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&latlng=53.477752,-2.266695&key=YOUR_API_KEY